# Turbo Repo Builds Even With Typescript Errors

Tags: typescript, npm, tsconfig, turborepo

I have a turborepo monorepo. The structure is something like this:

```
apps
|- app1
|- app2

packages
|- lib
   | .... some files
   |- tsconfig.json
   |- package.json
```

inside `lib` I have purposefully created a file with a blatant error. The error is reported in the editor while editing:

```
const a: String = 23;
console.log(a);
```

I am importing this file in one of my apps as well. When I try to build the project with `npm run build` it builds without any errors. I have no set option to ignore errors.

The build only fails if I put this purposefully error producing file in one of the apps. They it gives the correct error and aborts build.

This is the tsconfig for `lib`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */, // "lib": [],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify what module code is generated. */, // "rootDir": "./",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */, // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */ /* Type Checking */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */, // "noImplicitAny": true,                            /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["."],
  "exclude": ["dist", "build", "node_modules"]
}
```

I have a nearly identical tsconfig in my apps as well

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */, // "lib": [],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify what module code is generated. */, // "rootDir": "./",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */, // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */ /* Type Checking */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */, // "noImplicitAny": true,                            /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Installing a stable version of nodejs helped